# Syntax in Objective-C (may be cast syntax)

Tags: objective-c, object, syntax, casting

I am new to *Objective-C* and trying to undertand these syntax.

```
+ (MKCoordinateSpan)MKCoordinateSpan:(id)json
{
  json = [self NSDictionary:json];
  return (MKCoordinateSpan){
    [self CLLocationDegrees:json[@"latitudeDelta"]],
    [self CLLocationDegrees:json[@"longitudeDelta"]]
  };
}
```

Following what I guess, `MKCoordinateSpan` is a Class. And `{}` syntax try to create a object and cast these object into an instance `MKCoordinateSpan`. Is it correct? Or it try to create an object type `MKCoordinateSpan` with two value latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta

```
  (MKCoordinateSpan){
    [self CLLocationDegrees:json[@"latitudeDelta"]],
    [self CLLocationDegrees:json[@"longitudeDelta"]]
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKCoordinateSpan` is a `struct`, not a class. It is defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta;
} MKCoordinateSpan;
```

So, the code in your question is creating an instance of this `struct`.

A more customary way to achieve the same thing would be using `MKCoordinateSpanMake`:

```
+ (MKCoordinateSpan)MKCoordinateSpan:(id)json {
    json = [self NSDictionary:json];
    return MKCoordinateSpanMake([self CLLocationDegrees:json[@"latitudeDelta"]],
                                [self CLLocationDegrees:json[@"longitudeDelta"]]);
}
```

In the future, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter "oh"), and type `MKCoordinateSpan`, you can jump right to the definition of the type and remove any ambiguity. Or <kbd>alt</kbd>-click on the `MKCoordinateSpan` type in your code and you can see the quick help:

[image]

Comment: I'd also suggest breaking out the creation of the struct from the `return` statement.  Create and assign to a local variable, return the local variable.  The first time you step through said code in the debugger and need to print the values in the returned struct before return, you'll thank your former pedantic self.

Comment: @bbum - That doesn't make my list about what I don't like about this code snippet: What is `NSDictionary` method doing? If returning value, why is author changing value associated with method parameter? (Makes code hard to read IMHO.) If it's merely casting, then it offers no utility in this case. Or does it have some mysterious, unknown side effect? Why is he using type names for the names of his methods at all? Bottom line, I was trying to make the most modest change I could, eliminating the particular struct-building syntax and using the function that MapKit provided for this purpose.